# Tangled Tree Chart in d3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts

I am trying to build a chart as shown below using d3 charts in a React project. Anyone has any idea how to proceed with it. The tangled tree chart in d3 looks similar but I am not sure whether I should proceed with it since it has no working example in codesandbox and this is my first time using d3 charts. How should I proceed?

[image: Charts tangled]